# Android send SMS message with two getString()

Tags: android, string-concatenation, smsmanager, getstring

I've got some problem with sending sms from Android app.
In strings.xml I have text1 and text2 with some text.
When I'm trying to send sms with only one string, e.g

```
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null,message, null,null);
```

where message i getString(R.string.text1) it works fine. But what I need is send 
`String text = getString(R.string.text1) + someVariable + getString(R.string.text2);` but it doesn't work.
I've tried to make `getResources().getString()` in both but still nothing, it's not sending;/ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem? you can sand any message but this specific messsage fail?

Comment: If your concatenated String is over the character limit, you'll need to use the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method. `sendTextMessage()` will just fail silently in that case.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think about char limit, and also didn't know sendMultipartTextMessage() method, thanks a lot, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Builder to append all those string and put it together.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(some_appropriate_size);
sb.append(getResources().getString(R.string.text1));
sb.append(someVariable);
sb.append(getResources().getString(R.string.text2));

String final_string =  sb.toString();
```